# Overriding whoAmI in HDFS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I'm going through the definitive hadoop book.  In there the author describes how one can override the whoAmI mechanism by defining a `hadoop.job.ugi`.  Well, I'm not getting anywhere with it...

I'm using hduser@ubuntu (my box name).

I have created a localhost.conf to override the default conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>hadoop.job.ugi</name>
   <value>user, supergroup</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

but when I run `hadoop fs -conf localhost.conf -mkdir newDir` followed by `hadoop fs -conf localhost.conf -ls .` I see that the directory newDir is created by **hduser** and not by **user**

I must be missing a setting....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said that, you have used a localhost.conf but then why are you using a node.conf in the hadoop command?

Comment: @JtheRocker it was a mistype...i have several confs...the one I've posted is the localhost.  I've edited the question...thanks for pointing it out - but it doesn't solve my problem.